# length of a String with surrogate characters in it - java

Tags: java

I am having trouble counting the length of my `String` which has some surrogate characters in it ?

my String is,

```
String val1 = "\u5B66\uD8F0\uDE30";
```

The problem is, `\uD8F0\uDE30` is one character not two, so the length of the `String` should be `2`.

but when I am calculating the length of my `String` as `val1.length()` it gives `3` as output, which is totally wrong. how can I fix the problem and get the actual length of the `String`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `codePointCount(beginIndex, endIndex)` to count the number of code points in your `String` instead of using `length()`.

```
val1.codePointCount(0, val1.length())
```

See the following example,

```
String val1 = "\u5B66\uD8F0\uDE30";
System.out.println("character count: " + val1.length());
System.out.println("code points: "+ val1.codePointCount(0, val1.length()));
```

**output**

```
character count: 3
code points: 2
```

FYI, you cannot print individual surrogate characters from a `String` using `charAt()` either. 
In order to print individual *supplementary character* from a `String` use `codePointAt` and `offsetByCodePoints(index, codePointOffset)`, like this,

```
for (int i =0; i<val1.codePointCount(0, val1.length()); i++)
        System.out.println("character at " + i + ": "+ val1.codePointAt(val1.offsetByCodePoints(0, i)));
    }
```

gives,

```
character at 0: 23398
character at 1: 311856
```

### for Java 8

You can use `val1.codePoints()`, which returns an `IntStream` of all code points in the sequence.

Since you are interested in length of your `String`, use,

```
val1.codePoints().count();
```

to print code points,

```
val1.codePoints().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a));
```

Comment: Great answer.  Small technical quibble: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints() says that codePoints() was added in Java 9, not Java8.